# How to get the screen's size of a phone Android

Tags: java, android, screen, screen-resolution, screen-size

I want to get the size of the screen, I already have the resolution

```
 DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager windowmanager = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    windowmanager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    final int deviceWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    final int deviceHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
```

but I want the size in inches, like the Samsung Galaxy S7 has a resolution of 2560x1440 and a screen of 5.1" , it's the 5.1 I want to get.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int width=dm.widthPixels;
int height=dm.heightPixels;
double wi=(double)width/(double)dm.xdpi;
double hi=(double)height/(double)dm.ydpi;
double x = Math.pow(wi,2);
double y = Math.pow(hi,2);
double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x+y);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, it worked but for my S7 I get 5.093... How can I round this result to get 5.1 so I can display it clean

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java

Comment: You can use String.format("%.2f", d), your double will be rounded automatically.